# How to fix "cannot find entry point sqlite3_open_v2 in DLL sqlite3" when compiling SQLite from the source code?

Tags: c#, .net, c, sqlite

I am trying to compile sqlite from sources (amalgamation) to use it from C#. The reason to compile it myself rather than use precompiled version is that I need JSON support which is not included by default. This is how I compiled it:

```
cl sqlite3.c -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 -link -dll -out:sqlite3.dll
```

Then I tried to replace precompiled version of sqlite3.dll in my application with the version I compiled myself, and my C# application started to crash with EntryPointNotFoundException.

How to fix this, and what is the right way to compile SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to export the API functions:

```
cl sqlite3.c -DSQLITE_API=__declspec(dllexport) -link -dll -out:sqlite3.dll
```